# Not printing next line in the Excel file

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I am trying to read txt file and print line in the data.xls file. script is printing first line 6 times (duplicate entry) in the data.xls however script is not printing next line in the data.xls file. There are total 6 lines in the records.txt

This is how my records.txt file looks like as below:

```
"Userid","Subscriberid"
"167fgfg611","5904fds02"
"200fhskdhf","876fsgj25"
"3893fjs956","502sgfgg3"
"918shdfd71","1029gsg57"
Record Count: 4
```

After below script run then data.xls display as below:

```
"Userid","Subscriberid"
"Userid","Subscriberid"
"Userid","Subscriberid"
"Userid","Subscriberid"
"Userid","Subscriberid"
"Userid","Subscriberid"
```

Following are my code:

```
String st;

            int line;

        BufferedReader Br = null;

        File objFile = new File(
                "C:\\DATA\\records.txt");

        Br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(objFile));

        while ((st = Br.readLine()) != null) {

            LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(objFile));
            lineNumberReader.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            int lines = lineNumberReader.getLineNumber();

            lines++;

            String value = st.replace("\"", "");

            arraylist = value.split(",");

            FileOutputStream outFile1 = new FileOutputStream(
                    new File("C:\\DATA\\userdata.xls"));
            Workbook book = new HSSFWorkbook();
            Sheet sheet = book.createSheet("UserData");

            Row row = null;

            Cell cell = null;

            for (line = 0; line < lines; line++) {

                row = sheet.createRow(line);

                for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.length; i++) {                        

                    cell = row.createCell(i);

                    cell.setCellValue(arraylist[i]);

                }

            }

            book.write(outFile1);
            outFile1.close();
            Br.close();

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I was doing wrong in the loop. Initially, I kept following code in the loop:

```
FileOutputStream outFile1 = new FileOutputStream(
                        new File("C:\\DATA\\data.xls"));
                Workbook book = new HSSFWorkbook();
LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(objFile));
            lineNumberReader.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            int lines = lineNumberReader.getLineNumber();
            Sheet sheet = book.createSheet("UserData");
```

After removing above code from the While loop and keep them outside while loop, then I also removed `for (line = 0; line < lines; line++) {}` loop from the code and that make my code work.

Following are my updated code:

```
String st;

            BufferedReader Br = null;
            FileOutputStream outFile1 = new FileOutputStream(
                    new File("C:\\DATA\\data.xls"));
            Workbook book = new HSSFWorkbook();
            File objFile = new File(
                    "C:\\DATA\\records.txt");

            Br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(objFile));

            LineNumberReader lineNumberReader = new LineNumberReader(new FileReader(objFile));
            lineNumberReader.skip(Long.MAX_VALUE);
            int lines = lineNumberReader.getLineNumber();
            Sheet sheet = book.createSheet("UserData");

            System.out.println(lines);
            int line = 0;

            while ((st = Br.readLine()) != null) {

                String value = st.replace("\"", "");

                arraylist = value.split(",");

                Row row = null;

                Cell cell = null;

                row = sheet.createRow(line);

                for (int i = 0; i < arraylist.length; i++) {

                    // System.out.println(arraylist[i]);

                    cell = row.createCell(i);

                    cell.setCellValue(arraylist[i]);

                }

                line++;
                System.out.println("Line: " + line);

            }
            book.write(outFile1);
            outFile1.close();

            Br.close();
```